# Cant Remove Event Listener

Tags: javascript, canvas, addeventlistener

Im working on a simple Pong game with socket.io that will set the state.player to 0 to make the user the paddle on the left side of the screen, and state.player to 1 for the right side of the screen.

Eventually the players will switch positions and therefore the event listeners that let the mouse control the right/left side paddles on the screen need to be removed and re-added so that they control the correct paddle on the correct side of the screen.

I read somewhere that you have to store the function in a variable then call removeEventListener on the variable, but that doesn't seem to be working. I remove both event listeners before adding one so that the mouse should only control the correct paddle on the correct side of the screen.  But when they switch sides the mouse controls both sides.

```
const choosePlayerSide = (player) =>{

    function getLeftMouse(e){
            let mousePos = calcMousePos(e);         
            lpaddle.y = mousePos.y - PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2;
            socket.emit('mousePos', mousePos);              
    }

    function getRightMouse(e){
            let mousePos = calcMousePos(e);         
            rpaddle.y = mousePos.y - PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2;
            socket.emit('mousePos', mousePos);              
    }

    const gr = getRightMouse;
    const gl = getLeftMouse;

    if(player === 0){           
        console.log('choosing player 0')
        this.setPlayer(0);
        // Reset Event Listeners
        canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', gr);
        canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', gl);

        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', gl);

        this.setInPlay();
    }
    else if(player === 1){
        console.log('choosing player 1')
        this.setPlayer(1);

        canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', gr);
        canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', gl);

        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', gr);


        this.setInPlay();
        socket.emit('newplayer');

    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function declarations nested within another function's body create new function objects each time the outer function is called and executes.

So new instances of `getLeftMouse` and `getRightMouse` are created each time `choosePlayerSide` is called, and can't be used to remove an event listener added in a previous call.

A related error is to use function expressions in calls to `addEventListener`. This creates a new function each time an event listener is added, which can't be removed by repeating the same function expression in a statement calling `removeEventListener` later (evaluating each function expression creates a new and different function object). This is the source of the advice to "store the handler functions in a variable" to solve this version of the problem involving function expressions.

Note that `const` does not initialize a variable at compile time and store it for use across multiple calls. It protects a variable value from being modified after initialization, but executes the initialization each time the statement is executed within function code.

To solve the problem, declare `getLeftMouse` and `getRightMouse` at a more global level than `choosePlayerSide`. Depending on how the game app is put together this may be within an IEFE used to create the game or actually in global name space (not recommended). After doing this you can use their names in add/remove event listener calls without needing to replicate their values in local variables `gl` and `gr`.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you for the great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var _this = this;
addEventListener('click', this.clickhandler);
removeEventListener('click', this.clickhandler);
clickhander = (function () { _this.   ; }); //use _this inside
```